# Reconstructing Git Repository

Tags: git, restore

Suppose I have a git repository set up on a central server and cloned it to multiple machines. Suppose also that I have made modifications to the repo on some of the machines and pushed and pulled from a subset of those machines.

Question:
**If the central repository is deleted, is there an easy way to reconstruct the repository using only the (potentially inconsistent) cloned repositories on each of the machines?**

Comment: Hmm... Downvote without explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all clones are more-or-less trusted; on each clone, do:

```
git push --verbose origin "refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*"
git push --verbose origin "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"
```

This will push the results of the *last fetch*, resulting in mostly identical branches.

Afterwards manually go through each clone's *local* `master` and other branches, and push whatever's missing.